# External variable not updating correctly within success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm looping through an array of data, updating a variable named commentBody each time.

The variable is updated within the loop itself, but when I reference it from inside a success callback, it always output the final value of the array for all loops.

What am I missing?

```
for (var p = 0; p < data.comments.length; p++) {

    var commentBody = data.comments[p].comment;

    var authorName = "not set yet";

    getName(data.comments[p].userId).success(function(a) {

          authorName = a.username;
          setter();

    });

     console.log(commentBody); // CORRECT = DIFFERENT VALUE EACH TIME

     var setter = function() {

           console.log(commentBody); // SAME VALUE FOR ALL INTERATIONS 

      };

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`commendBody` variable is not local to for loop but is the same variable that gets updated every time in the iteration. 

So, when setter method is called, `commentBody` refers to the value at that time. 

Considering `getName` is **async**, all getName success functions are called after for loop is finished. So, by the time setter function is invoked,  `commentBody` holds the last value in for loop and so all setter functions print the same value.

do this:

```
//commentBody is passed as local variable (a copy) to the function
var setter = (function(c){ console.log(c); })(commentBody);
```